# Missing value_equal in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I noticed that `std::unordered_map` does not provide a member class that allows equivalence comparison between two value_type, like `value_compare` in `std::map`.
Is there a reason therefore the member class has never been introduced?

Comment: std::unordered_map unlike std::map is not heap but hash table.

Comment: Probably omitted  because the items in `unordered_map` aren't compared since they aren't ordered. They're hashed.

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that this feature in `std::map` was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20. So it is good it is not in `std::unordeded_map`.

Comment: @MarekR, I do not see in cppreference that the member class  was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20, but only its member types. Am I mistaking?

Comment: @LoS [std::map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>::value_compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/value_compare)

Comment: @MarekR That only says that the old parameter/result member typedefs for function objects were removed (as in all function objects in the standard library).

Comment: there is `hash_function` and `key_eq` in `unordered_map`, thats all you need. I find `value_compare` a little pointless, it looks redundant when there is already `key_compare`

Comment: fwiw here is the proposal to introduce `unordered_map` (among others). It has only `hash_funciton` and `key_eq`, no `value_eq`. I didnt check if some motivation is given, but if anywhere I'd expect it in there https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1456.html

Comment: @user4581301 *"the items in `unordered_map` aren't compared since they aren't ordered"* -- "Not ordered" is why the comparison is for equivalence rather than for "less than". They are still compared (when multiple entries end up in the same bucket).